# How can I suppress startup error E575?

Tags: neovim, error

If I quit Neovim's containing terminal without exiting Vim first, then the next time I run Neovim I get the error:

```
E575: Error while reading ShaDa file: mark entry at position 2957 has
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

I want to not see this error on startup.

To reproduce this error run `nvim --cmd term` exit the terminal while still in vim and then run `nvim --cmd term` again. This error is caused by not exiting vim before closing the terminal.

Comment: Why are they unavoidable?  I see various issues in the github repo, which have all been resolved.  Please provide more information.

Comment: Based on [`:h E575`](https://neovim.io/doc/user/starting.html#E575) and the error message you have corrupted data in your shada file. I'm not familiar with neovim but [`:h shada-file-name`](https://neovim.io/doc/user/starting.html#shada-file-name) seems to indicate where is your shada file. So find your shada file, find the corrupted data and no more "unavoidable error"

Comment: @statox quitting the terminal without closing vim causes this error. The error corrects it's self if I open and then close vim.

Answer (score 6):

Check your `init.vim`. If there is any line concerning `viminfo`, temporarily remove/comment it, you can later discover the reason it messed up.

Then backup and remove `~/.local/share/nvim/shada` folder. Then start up Neovim, the folder will be auto-generated with a file named `main.shada`. Hopefully, your error will be gone.

The error possibly surfaced because neovim deprecated vim's `viminfo` format. Instead neovim uses `shada` or `shared data`. But possibly your `init.vim` contains some reference to `viminfo` formatted code which it can't read.

Comment: Nothing concerning viminfo.

Comment: Check the question for new details. I am not necessarily looking to get rid of the error, just to hide it.

Comment: Sorry, but I couldn't reproduce the error. I'm using v.0.2.3-dev.

Answer (score 0):

if you are a linux user:

```
echo ':term' | nvim
```

will send the commands directly through the pipe. So there won't be any error.

I personally also put an alias into my `.bashrc` file too:

```
alias nvim='echo ":term" | nvim'
```

---

Edit:
If you still want to open files with nvim you might want to put something like this into your `bashrc` file (and remove the alias)

```
nvim() {
    if [[ $@ == "." ]]; then
        command echo ":terminal" | nvim
    else
        command nvim "$@"
    fi
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure your answer will change something about OP's issue: Passing a command to neovim will not make it ignore the `shada` files containing some errors. Also, the recommended way to pass a command to vim is with `+c` ([`:h -c`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/starting.txt.html#-c)) and I think this is the same for neovim (but I may be wrong about this part).

Comment: You are right it won't help you if you already have some errors in your shada file. But with this method you can exit the terminal without vim exiting first without throwing a error.